# Basic XE7 webbroker app causes error in IIS7.5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, datasnap, webbroker

Create a "basic" Webbroker dll in the IDE using the wizard. File->New->Other->WebBroker. Make no changes to the code. Save project as WebISAPI and compile.

Configure IIS 7.5 (on Win7) to host the dll according to Char Chee Yang's excellent article at

http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2009/10/configure-windows-7-iis7-for-isapi-dll.html.

Access the application in the webbrowser:
http://localhost/webISAPI/

> DataSnap Server

Start the IIS Manager.

Select Application Pools - > Default App Pool -> in the Actions pane, click recycle.

> An unhandled 32 bit exception occurred

Click Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Event Viewer and select the event that just occurred.

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
>   Faulting module name: WebISAPI.dll, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54f1df76
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x000083e2
>   Faulting process id: 0x1c34
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d05445e9f37798
>   Faulting application path: C:\windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   Faulting module path: \?\C:\Delphi Development\WebISAPI\Win32\Debug\WebISAPI.dll
>   Report Id: 34c84cee-c039-11e4-b96a-001e101f63cf

Has anyone else encountered this problem and if so, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you compile as 64bit or 32 bit?

Comment: 32 bit. I also enabled 32bit applications in Advanced Settings of the DefaultAppPool.

Comment: I had some time, added 64 bit platform. 64bit dll produces error 500!

Comment: Default App pool has setting to toggle between 32bit and 64 bit. When correctly set for app, app works as expected. 64bit XE7 dll also shuts down badly (like 32bit dll)

Comment: last note: No such problem occurs using the same dll's on IIS 8.0. So it's definitely an IIS 7.5 issue. Hope this helps someone else.